# How to check if any row is added to Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindingsource

I am using a Datagridview control on winform and a bindingsource for data. Data is filled in bindingsource and accordingly datagridview is populated. I am looking for an event or something like that which will fire up when a row from bindingsource is added to the datagridview.

I want to perform some operations over the added row. I tried with RowsAdded event but e.RowIndex is not being retrieved properly.

**Edit1:** Let's say I am having 10 records in database table. I am fetching these into bindingsource and using bindingsource as a datasource for Datagridview. Now while adding row to Datagridview, I want to perform some UI operations on the Datagridview. I used RowsAdded event but it is giving me RowIndex as 0 or 1 always. I also tried a foreach loop over RowsCount, and if I debug the code, the execution flow is as per the expectations, but on the UI it is not getting reflected. I have called Datagridview1.refresh() after everything is done.

Can you please help me out to get this ?

Comment: There is also a `RowCount` property maybe that could help in fixing your index issue (just a guess since you didn't explain what is the issue) *not being retrieved properly* doesn't say much !

Comment: Really sorry for short description. Actually I am also not getting how should I explain the scenario. Please find Edit1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the user adds a new row using the row for new records, the DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs.RowIndex value in the handler for this event is equal to the index of the new location of the row for new records, which is one greater than the row just added.

> When you add rows programmatically, however, the RowIndex value is the
>   index of the first row added.

```
private void dataGridView1_NewRowNeeded(object sender,
    DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    newRowNeeded = true;
}

private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender,
     DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    if (newRowNeeded)
    {
        newRowNeeded = false;
        numberOfRows = numberOfRows + 1;
    }
}
```

will fetch you the exact row refer [msdn rowadded link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsadded.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the operations you wish to perform after binding you could use Control.BindingContextChanged event to iterate on the grid rows:

```
private void dataGridView1_BindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    foreach (var row in dataGridView1.Rows) {

    }
}
```

If it's not working could you say what exactly are you trying to accomplish after binding?

Comment: This is working for the first iteration. When I click a menu item to open the form, for the first time UI changes are reflected. But if I open the same from menu item, without closing the form, the UI changes are not applied. ( I am changing BackColor, of some of the cells).

Comment: I created a form with a button and opened on click 2 instances of another form having the grid. I added code in the above method to change the bg color of some cell and the changes are reflected in both opened instances, so cannot reproduce